# Write a function to work for a single element

Tags: javascript

I've got this function.

```
function getInfo(){    
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inStock'), function(img){
      var newImg = document.createElement('img');
      newImg.src = img.src;
      ..........
    });
}
```

Instead of using `[]forEach` or haveing the function work for a whole class `.inStock`, How do I write this function to work for a single element using its ID?

So basically I want to be able to have `function(img){` working as it is but to replace `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inStock')` by `document.getElementById('singleElemID')`. How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to consider using `map` over an array of elements then passing a function into map. Much cleaner functional style then what you have here.

Comment: Down-voter : Please leave a comment as to why I was down voted. That helps.

Comment: @jeanpier_re thanks. But I want to make this work for a single element. I do not know how to combine `document.getElementById('singleElemID')` with `function(img){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getInfo(){
  var img = document.getElementById('whatever');
  var newImg = document.createElement('img');
  newImg.src = img.src;
  //...
}
```

Comment: @Bekki Glad to help you. Don't forget to mark the best answer with the green tick under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You have to extract the inner function from the call instruction; that way you'll be able to call it not only from the call instruction, but also in a "stand-alone" way:

```
function createImage(img) {
    var newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.src = img.src;
    // ..........
}

function getInfo() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inStock'), createImage);
}

// Stand-alone:
createImage(document.getElementById('singleElemID');
```

Comment: @Bekki this answer is more I was talking about in my other comment. Glad you resolved this.